# How to retrieve documents in collection based on particular field in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Database Structure

```
- `VHpHJDSvjyYmAteoQEu0AeEHWVg2` [collection]
  - `LI4deUjJK3uqOGhMLDfR` [document]
    - `Gallery` [collection]
      - `RjuCvHvuoz2GRW4Rkuyi` [document]
        - `attachmentId` [field]
        - `type` [field]
```

To get all documents in collection `Gallery`

```
Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection(userId).document(docTripId).collection("Gallery");
```

How to retrieve documents in collection `Gallery` based on field `type` equals "camera"?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be something like this:

```
CollectionReference  collection = firebaseFirestore.collection(userId).document(docTripId).collection("Gallery");

Query query = collection.whereEqualTo("type", "camera");
```

And then you either [get the results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), or [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Comment: in this case, you are fetching the entire document right?

Comment: The above code doesn't actually retrieve anything yet, but if call `getDocuments()` on it, it'll indeed get the entire document. That is the only level that the Firestore clients deal with: you cannot get a subset of a document.